# What is the type of derefenced pointer or iterator?

Tags: c++, dereference, decltype

If I have something like this:

```
int a = 5;
auto* p = &a;
decltype(*p) b = 1;
```

I'd guess that `decltype(*p)` is `int` and not `int&` or `const int&`.

But then what about dereferencing an iterator, e.g.

```
std::vector<int> a { 5 };
auto it = a.begin();
decltype(*it) b = 1;
```

Is `decltype(*it)` `int`? But isn't the type of `*it` `int&`?

I suspect that the answer is contained in item (4) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), but I'm still confused about *xvalue* and *prvalue*.

**Edit**: In the original code that confused me, I must have had something equivalent to

```
const int a = 5;
auto* p = &a;
decltype(*p) b = 1;
```

and not realized that `a` is `const`, so `decltype(*p)` was `const int&` and that's why the third line was fine.

Comment: Hint: the Type of `*p` is also `int&`

Comment: So, in which cases does `decltype` strip off the reference? Does it ever add reference?

Comment: `decltype` gives you the exact type. Why do do you think you lose the ref?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `*p` and `*it` give you an `int&`, which is a lvaue reference to an `int`.  Since you have an lvalue `decltype(lvalue)` gives you a `T&`.

That means in both code blocks `b` is an `int&` and the code wont compile as you cannot bind a prvalue (`1` in this case) to a non-const lvalue reference